# In react, what is the best method to run sequence of functions until await/async completes? - using the execution time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

**The goal:**
I want to be able to show few html lines while await is waiting to complete. For example..

```html
<p>starting api</p>
<p>loading</p>
<p>getting api</p>
```

I just want these to load in delay (maybe i can use a timeout function), but all in all, if the await completes these p tags disappear and all the user sees is

done!

**The problem:**
I don't need to know how to implement timeout function or how to do conditional rendering in react. What I want to know is how do I use the "wait" time - time that it takes for the await to complete (usually a few seconds) and display certain text on the page to mimic the progress?

**current solution**

Please ignore my catch error block as i don't have setTimeout implemented in that. But basically here I am delaying what the user sees even though the api call completes in like 2 seconds. This is a workaround, this is more for the ux. But I am wondering if I can tap into the execution time and display msges.

```js
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        status: {
          ...prevState.status,
          start: true
        }
      }));
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        status: {
          ...prevState.status,
          api: true
        }
      }));
    }, 2000);

    try {
      let data = await this.getlogin();

      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          status: {
            ...prevState.status,
            start: true,
            api: true
          },
          done: {
            ...prevState.done,
            done: true
          }
        }));
      }, 3000);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        status: {
          ...prevState.status,
          start: true,
          api: true
        },
        done: {
          ...prevState.done,
          done: false
        }
      }));
    }
  };
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an accurate solution without a working snippet but here's an example of conditional rendering :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startingApi: false,
    loadingApi: false,
    gettingApi: false
  }
  
  handleClick = () => { 
    this.setState({startingApi: true, loadingApi: true, gettingApi: true});
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({startingApi: false});
    }, 1000);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({loadingApi: false});
    }, 2000);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({gettingApi: false});
    }, 3000);
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get Data</button>
        <div>
          {this.state.startingApi 
            ? <React.Fragment>
                <img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ZealousCloudyAntelopegroundsquirrel-small.gif" /> 
                Starting API
              </React.Fragment>
            : "Api started"
          }
        </div>
        <div>  
          {this.state.loadingApi 
            ? <React.Fragment>
                <img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ZealousCloudyAntelopegroundsquirrel-small.gif" /> 
                Loading API
              </React.Fragment>
            : "Api Loaded"
          }
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.gettingApi 
            ? <React.Fragment>
                <img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ZealousCloudyAntelopegroundsquirrel-small.gif" /> 
                Getting API
              </React.Fragment>
            : "Api Gotten"
          }
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. This is a good solution, but i am wondering is there no way to tap into  the async/await to render html? As an alternative to using setTimeout?

Comment: `setTimeout` is just for the example, you should replace it with your async functions

Comment: is there no way for me to run a timer/function UNTIL async/wait finishes? Instead of doing setTimeout? I want to DO something while waiting for response of async

Comment: you don't need a timer at all, set the state ( loading ) to `true` after the await